# mathcad programming error :This array index is invalid for this array

Tags: arrays, graph, mathcad

I use mathcad program.
I want to have "sys_r" graph.
graph shape example below
[image]

I try a below programming.

[image]

But programming error occurred.
programming error!

> Error is "This array index is invalid for this array."

I don't know solution.
Please help me.

please........

Comment: Exactly what array are you talking about (based on the suggested edit)? I don't have permission to see either of your images.

Comment: edit url, look graph and programming code

Comment: https://www.ptcusercommunity.com/community/mathcad is a good place for the mathcad user community, despite it being the vendors site ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in your `for` loop. `j` goes from `0` to `2`, so `j+1` can take the value `3`, which is an invalid index for the matrix (it is a 3x3 matrix, not a 4x4 one). Hence the "invalid index" out-of-bounds access error.

Your outer `for` loop will cause an out-of-bounds access error too, even if you fix this, because `i` goes from `1` to `3`.

If you weren't aware of that, matrices (and vectors) in Mathcad are indexed beginning with `0`, just like in any other programming language. So, the valid indexes for your matrix are from `0` to `2` inclusive in both dimensions.